# Adventureworks multi-part identifier cannot be bound question

Tags: sql, multipart, identifier, adventureworks

I'm beginning to learn SQL and I'm somewhat familiar with joins, but I have a question about this example code below.

```
USE AdventureWorks2017
GO

SELECT
    Detail.SalesOrderID,
    Detail.SalesOrderDetailID,
    Product.Name as ProductName,
    Product.ProductNumber,
    Product.Color,
    Detail.CarrierTrackingNumber,
    Detail.OrderQty,
    Detail.UnitPrice,
    Detail.Linetotal,
    Header.OrderDate,
    Header.DueDate,
    Header.ShipDate,
    Territory.Name as TerritoryName,
    Territory.CountryRegionCode as TerritoryRegion,
    Territory.[Group] as TerritoryGroup
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail Detail
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader Header ON Header.SalesOrderID = Detail.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory Territory ON Territory.TerritoryID = Header.TerritoryID
INNER JOIN Production.Product ON Product.ProductID = Detail.ProductID
```

Specifically this one:

```
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail Detail
```

Why do we write Detail here again? The code won't run without it and throws a 'multi-part identifier cannot be bound' error message. I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

In the query, `detail` (and `Header`, `Territory`) etc are known as `aliases`.

The point is that you can provide a "short hand" to use as a reference to that object elsewhere in the query - like you can see on the first lines eg `Detail.SalesOrderID`; Without using the (optional) alias this would have to be `Sales.SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID`.

If you remove the alias then everywhere the alias is used elsewhere in the query will have to be "fully qualified" with the actual table's name - otherwise you'll see the `multi-part identifier cannot be bound` message - you've used a reference that cannot be bound to a base table.

This is not a great example of using aliases as ideally they should be short, brief and quick to type - eg using `sod` for `SalesOrderDetail`, `st` for `SalesTerritory` etc would make the query more compact and easier to read.